# Kubectl asking: error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, kubectl, amazon-ecr

Trying to "Kubectl get ns" and getting this error.
been looking at most of the articles in here but didn't find a real solution.
made pure new policies, roles clusters IAM user everything.. even tried to open a new EC2 to make sure it's not a problem i made while troubleshooting on the old one.

anyone had same error before?

for context

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region eu-north-1 --name OneCluster --role-arn arn:aws:iam::fakenumber:role/OneRole
```

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AIDARAIVMLW6ZZUUK4CLH",
    "Account": "fakenumber",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::fakenumber:user/MainZolo"
```

````
aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AIDARAIVMLW6ZZUUK4CLH",
    "Account": "fakenumber",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::fakenumber:user/MainZolo"
}
kubectl config view --minify
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://20C9AD9474B6C3D3480652297F89CDCF.gr7.eu-north-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:fakenumber:cluster/OneCluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:fakenumber:cluster/OneCluster
    user: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:fakenumber:cluster/OneCluster
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:fakenumber:cluster/OneCluster
current-context: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:fakenumber:cluster/OneCluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:fakenumber:cluster/OneCluster
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - OneCluster
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env: null
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
    ```
````

**I've also viewed:**
[How do I resolve the error "You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)" when I connect to the Amazon EKS API server?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error)

and got the results in cloudwatch of:

```
2023-08-07T22:45:48.899+03:00
time="2023-08-07T19:45:44Z" level=info msg="access granted" arn="arn:aws:iam::069301198269:root" client="127.0.0.1:34550" groups="[system:masters]" method=POST path=/authenticate uid="aws-iam-authenticator:069301198269:069301198269" username=kubernetes-admin
Field   Value
@ingestionTime  
1691437549781
@log    
069301198269:/aws/eks/OneCluster/cluster
@logStream  
authenticator-d5c6ff557d720035f94e19838546d748
@message    
time="2023-08-07T19:45:44Z" level=info msg="access granted" arn="arn:aws:iam::069301198269:root" client="127.0.0.1:34550" groups="[system:masters]" method=POST path=/authenticate uid="aws-iam-authenticator:069301198269:069301198269" username=kubernetes-admin
@timestamp  
1691437548899
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created a cluster, and you are using the same IAM user, and  you still get errors like "error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)", "Identity is not mapped", "Your current IAM principal doesn't have access to Kubernetes objects on this cluster. This might be due to the current principal not having an IAM access entry with permissions to access the cluster." from CLI (kubectl), CloudWatch, and Console respectively, then you have to go to the cluster from the AWS console, access tab, create access entry, select the ARN of your principal (you can see it from CLI with command aws sts get-caller-identity), add access policy, select AmazonEKSAdminPolicy, create and go back to the access tab, click on the access entry you added for your user ARN, add access policy, select AmazonEKSClusterAdminPolicy and try running the kubectl commands again.